# Pyplot Scatter Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm not great at matplotlib, but I need to use it for some work I am doing. I have a set of 9 columns of data, with around 100k lines. I want to produce a scatter plot, and I don't care about the rows, they're meaningless for my purposes. What I need is for the values to be plotted as a scatter against which column they are in, regardless of which row they a part of.

This is all loaded in from a text file in a simple 2D array using numpy.loadtxt. It's just a set of numbers, so any substitution of random numbers should work. I'm just not sure how to manipulate it in a way that the scatter command will like. I often get it giving me errors like I'm giving it too few arguments, or it just iterates over the array (or arrays if I separate them), in ways I do not anticipate.

My first thought is that I could somehow break it down into a set of series by column, but I don't think the scatter command will take that. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Since you already have it in a numpy array, all you need to do is `data[:, 0]` to access the first column. To scatter the second column vs. the first, just do `plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:,1])`.

Comment: See, I tried that, but instead I get two series of 100k results being plotted against each other, which isn't quite what I'm after.

Comment: Then what are you after? Do you want a scatter where all values in column 1 are at x = 1? For that, just do `plt.scatter([1]*len(data), data[:, 0])`, and repeat for all columns.

Comment: @ArthurDent That doesn't seem to quite get what we're looking for either. There's 9 coloumns, and that produces [this](http://imgur.com/a/KFXqG) . It's getting closer to the goal, but as you can see I'm looking for something like 1-9 on the x-axis and to actually have it spread out along those columns. I've used the same code you wrote, with a simple for loop over the number of columns.

Comment: By "repeat for all columns", I meant changing the `1` corresponding to whichever column you're using. So after the above line, do `plt.scatter([2]*len(data), data[:, 1])` for column 2, then `plt.scatter([3]*len(data), data[:, 2])` for column 3, etc. Of course, it would be easier to loop from 0 to 8: `for i in range(9):; plt.scatter([i+1]*len(data), data[:, i])`. The `[1]*len(data)` line is just creating a list of 1s that has the same length as your data.

Comment: @ArthurDent ah, yup that makes a lot more sense given how plotting works. I wasn't iterating in the loop on the x range. Thanks! Mind posting it as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Also to whoever downvoted this question, I can't imagine why. Maybe clarifying why would be helpful. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scatter` function takes in two lists that have the same length. To access a single column `n` of your numpy array, just use `data[:, n]`. Since you want to correspond all columns with their column number, you need to also create a list that has the same length of `data`, with only the column number as elements. To create the plot you want, just do the following:

```
for i in range(9):
    plt.scatter([i + 1] * len(data), data[:, i])
```